# Php - Find only one number in a string

Tags: php

I have a php script that loads different IDs and send them to a page on a GET variable, they are all separated by a coma:

```
.../page.php?items=12,13,43,17,
```

I then load a mysql with a while loop so that a table shows up, and I need to see if the id of the table item is the same then it adds a style to that table row.

So what I did was:

```
$style = (strstr($_GET['ids'], $segn['itemid'])) ? 'style="background:lightgreen;"' : '' ;
<tr class="gradeX" <?= $style ?> >;
```

In this case it worked for single numbers. But in case i have this `IDS: 1, 2, 3 ... 12` and the page get request is `"page.php?items=12"` I get the ids `'12'`, `'1'` and `'2'`.

I thought i could use `explode(',' , $_GET['ids'])` but then I guess it goes too long.

How do I get those the ids? (I've no affinity whatsoever for regexp...).

Comment: use $arr = explode(',', $_GET['ids']) to convert in array and then use in_array($segn['itemid'], $arr) in your condition

Comment: Why don't you use an actual GET array `ids[]`?

Comment: OK SmasherHell, that's the correct answer!!! Tku!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
strstr($_GET['ids'], $segn['itemid'])
```

You could do this:

```
in_array($segn['itemid'], explode(',',$_GET['ids']));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to work with the ids as an array, not as a string. So make an array first:

```
$ids = explode(',', $_GET['items']);
```

And then check if the current item is in the array:

```
$style = in_array($segn['itemid'], $ids) ? 'style="background:lightgreen;"' : '';
```

That said, you should be using a CSS class instead of inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this. 
Split your get variable using explodes as you did:

```
$items = explode(",", $_GET['items']);
```

Be careful- you used the wrong name in your code (your get variable is "items", not "ids");

and then use in_array to check to see if it's in there.

```
$style = in_array($segn['itemid'], $items) ? 'style="background:lightgreen;"' : '';
```